# Is there a way to download captured webM/mp4 video that displays both visual and audio content?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, mp4

I'm trying to create a tool where people can capture video directly in their browser using their webcam and then download that video locally. Right now, the video they capture is saved on the browser and displays fully in the window, but upon download, only the audio content of the mp4 file saves with no visual component. I've pasted my code below, any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    .then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
        let video = document.querySelector('video');
        if ("srcObject" in video) {
            video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
        } else {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
        }
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
            video.play();
        };
        let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
        let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
        let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
        let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
        let chunks = [];
        let blob = undefined
        start.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        })
        stop.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        });
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
            chunks.push(ev.data);
        }
        mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) => {
            blob = new Blob(chunks);
            chunks = [];
            let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            vidSave.src = videoURL;
            document.getElementById("download").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = videoURL;
                document.getElementById("downloadLink").download = "video.mp4";
                document.getElementById("downloadLink").click();
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name, err.message);
    });
```

Comment: could you please provide us with an [mcve]?

Comment: the snippet has been edited to be minimal :)